# What are hiccups?

Tags: human-biology

What are hiccups?How are they generated and are they involuntary?Does it happen when we eat something tart?Or is there any other cause?I tried to find the solution but I always got different answers

Comment: This can be answered by a simple Google search. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiccup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is essentially the phrenic nerve being irritated and as such the diaphragm (innervated by the phrenic nerve) contracts when involuntary signals are generated as a result of the irritation.

This irritation can occur for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Overall great answer; however, it is highly recommended that you add some references, otherwise the answer may be downvoted and/or removed.